# Object/factory with type BookDataSource is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection

There are several similar topics about my issue but mine is a little bit awkward.  I have get_it locator file and I register some modules in it.

```
GetIt instance = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initAppModule() async {
  //this works
  final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  //this works
  instance.registerLazySingleton<SharedPreferences>(() => sharedPrefs);
  
  //this works
  instance.registerLazySingleton<AppPrefences>(() => AppPrefences(instance()));
  
  //this DOESN'T work (throws -> object/factory with  type DataConnectionChecker is not 
  //registered inside GetIt. 
  instance.registerLazySingleton<DataConnectionChecker>(() => DataConnectionChecker());
  
  //this works
  instance.registerLazySingleton<HasuraConnection>(() => HasuraConnection());
  
  //this DOESN'T work
  instance.registerFactory<NetworkInfoBase>(() => NetworkInfo(DataConnectionChecker()));

  //this DOESN'T work (throws -> object/factory with  type BookBaseDataSource is not 
  //registered inside GetIt.
  instance.registerFactory<BookBaseDataSource>(() => BookDataSource());

  //this DOESN'T work (throws -> object/factory with  type FetchAllBooksUsecase is not 
  //registered inside GetIt.
  instance.registerFactory<FetchAllBooksUsecase>(() => FetchAllBooksUsecase(instance()));

  //this DOESN'T work (throws -> object/factory with  type BookRepository is not 
  //registered inside GetIt.
  instance.registerLazySingleton<BookBaseRepository>(() => BookRepository(instance(), instance()));
```

I also initialize it in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initAppModule();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Some of my modules work fine bu some throw "Not registered inside geIt" error. Thanks in advance.